# Amazon Mechanical Turk ExternalQuestions Image URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to make an ExternalQuestion HIT and was wondering how I could pass S3 image URLs to the hit and display them.

I considered passing the URL as a url parameter but that doesn't make sense since it's a url.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<ExternalQuestion xmlns="[the ExternalQuestion schema URL]">
  <ExternalURL>http://tictactoe.amazon.com/gamesurvey.cgi?gameid=01523</ExternalURL>
  <FrameHeight>400</FrameHeight>
  <ImageURL1>[image_url]</ImageURL1>
  <ImageURL2>[image_url]</ImageURL2>
   ....
</ExternalQuestion>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do something like what the Requester User Interface does when creating a batch, which involves building an HTMLQuestion out of a template HTML page with some named variables and a CSV file containing the values for each variable.

The ExternalQuestion only contains the ExternalURL and FrameHeight parameters. If you want to display different images, those need to be on their own pages (i.e., your server needs to decide what image to display to a given worker OR you have to create multiple HITs, one for each page that contains a distinct URL).